# If-statement with logical OR

Tags: programming-languages

```
 public class Test{
      public static void main(String args[]){
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 10;
    if ( a == 0 || b++ == c ){
        a = b + c;
    }else{
        b = a + c;
    }
    System.out.println("a: " + a + ",b: " + b + ",c: " + c);
    }
}
```

Ok, this is Java code and the output is
a: 11,b: 1,c: 10
And I believe the C acts same as Java in this case

That is because second condition(b++ == c) would never executed if the first condition is true in 'OR' operator.

There is a "NAME" for this. I just don't remember what it is.
Does anyone know what this is called??

Answer (score 10):

short circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 5):

This is called [`short-circuit`](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaIntro/contents.html) behavior of the logical operator:

> With the short-circuit versions, evaluation of subsequent subexpressions is abandoned as soon as a sub expression evaluates to false (in the case of &&) or true (in the case of ||).